# How to create simple product using direct SQL queries?

Tags: database, magento2.3

I know direct SQL query is not good practice, but I need to insert product using direct SQL query.
Also they do not want to use REST API for that.
Anyone has SQL queries to create a simple product with all the fields.

Comment: what fields of product you want to insert?

Answer (score 2):

Magento using **EAV** Structure for store product data. So, using single query it quit impossible or direct query, save product data, not possible.

https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/eav-database-structure/

There are a lot of tables and lots of related tables has used to save data for the product. So my suggestions to avoid the idea of using query save a product full data at the database, if you are new at Magento.

If you have talked about a single field/attribute save of this might be easy to answer. But you must have an idea of EAV data pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This query can help you out

1. insert new product

INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`, `attribute_set_id`, `type_id`, `sku`, `has_options`, `required_options`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (NULL, '4', 'simple', 'my-sku-test', '0', '0', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
[get entity id of new product]

2. Set status of new product using entity_id

INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_int` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES (NULL, '97', '1', '17', '1');

3. Set visibility of product using entity_id

INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_int` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES (NULL, '99', '0', '17', '4')

4. Set tax_class_id of product

INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_int` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES (NULL, '134', '0', '17', '0')

5. Set filter_price_range of product

INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_decimal` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES (NULL, '77', '0', '17', '100');

6. Set weight of product

INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_decimal` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES (NULL, '82', '0', '17', '10')

7. Set quantity of product

INSERT INTO `cataloginventory_stock_item` (`item_id`, `product_id`, `stock_id`, `qty`, `min_qty`, `use_config_min_qty`, `is_qty_decimal`, `backorders`, `use_config_backorders`, `min_sale_qty`, `use_config_min_sale_qty`, `max_sale_qty`, `use_config_max_sale_qty`, `is_in_stock`, `low_stock_date`, `notify_stock_qty`, `use_config_notify_stock_qty`, `manage_stock`, `use_config_manage_stock`, `stock_status_changed_auto`, `use_config_qty_increments`, `qty_increments`, `use_config_enable_qty_inc`, `enable_qty_increments`, `is_decimal_divided`, `website_id`) VALUES (NULL, '17', '1', '1000', '0.0000', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1.0000', '1', '0.0000', '1', '0', NULL, NULL, '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0.0000', '1', '0', '0', '0');

8. Set name of product

INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_varchar` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES (NULL, '73', '0', '17', 'my-sku-test');

9. Set url of product

INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_varchar` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES (NULL, '121', '0', '17', 'my-sku-test');